# Right click and perform action using Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wanted to right-click and perform an action using Selenium but I couldn't do it. I am able to right-click but it doesn't perform the action. I hope anyone can help me with this. Below is the code.

Thanks...

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path='C:\\Users\\Sheik\\Desktop\\web crawling\\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xSc5NYKZQaun3B4LARLZ"
driver.get(url)
save_video = driver.find_element_by_name('media')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.context_click(save_video).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pyautogui you can press the down arrow outside of the context of the web page. Below will select the first option of the context minu.
Try this:

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pyautogui

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path='C:\\Users\\Sheik\\Desktop\\web crawling\\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xSc5NYKZQaun3B4LARLZ"
driver.get(url)
save_video = driver.find_element_by_name('media')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.context_click(save_video).perform()
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('down')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: docs on pyautogui:
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html